# Different toolbars on the product page

Tags: magento-1.7, toolbar

How to have different toolbars for top and bottom of products page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your template folder (or `base` if you don't have a custom theme) create the file `toolbar-bottom.phtml` in `catalog/product/list`. Then in `catalog/product/list.phtml` file call your bottom toolbar with:

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarBlock()->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar-bottom.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

If you dont want to change the `toolbar.phtml` then follow the same steps for toolbar-top.